# Hide Article in Joomla Section but show in Category?

Tags: joomla, categories, joomla-article

I've created a new set of articles under a new category, within an existing section. When you visit the section "Services & Pricing" you get a complete list of all articles on the site within this section. There however is one article that I do not want to show at the section level but still need it to show in the category page.

Is there any way I can prevent the article in question from displaying at the top level "section" but still display in the lower level "category"?

Answer (score 0):

No. All articles are inherited Section > Category > Item. I'd suggest moving the individual article to a custom html module, then you can put it on whatever page you want.